# Ubuntu 12.04 on VMware Player loses network configuration

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, vmware-player

I've been having this issue for 2 weeks now with my VMware Player-hosted Ubuntu 12.04. I only use it for my LAMP stack. I've had no issues with it before until about 2 weeks ago when it almost always (once per day at least) loses its network configuration. On boot it shows:

```
Waiting for network configuration...
Waiting up to 60 more seconds for network configuration...
Booting system without full network configuration...
```

Then when I do `ifconfig -a` it doesn't show an IP Address and couldn't get online. The only resolutions I've found so far was either to reinstall VMware Tools or use the VMware Player installer and choose Repair.

This is frustrating to me because even when the issue was resolved after doing either of the steps I mentioned, the IP Address gets changed. Then I'd have to update the Remote Configuration of my IDE (Netbeans) and my database manager.

What could possible cause this? Please help. Thank you.

Additional details: I'm using a laptop with Windows 7 and connected to the office WiFi, which is unrestricted as far as I know. Thanks again.

Comment: Does your laptop with Windows 7 also lose connection when the VM does?

Comment: @Rudolph No, it does not lose the connection, just the VM.

Answer (score 0):

How is the VM's hardware configured?  If you use bridged networking it should behave like any other physical computer.

THis also allows you to add a reserved MAC:IP tupel to your DHCP server and it always gets the same IP while keeping one place (your SoHo/Router/modem/switch) to manage all network configurations.